# "Script Error." errors in window.onerror in Safari only

Tags: javascript, html, safari, cors, onerror

I'm getting "Script Error." when catching errors in window.onerror, even with properly (I think) configured CORS headers on S3.

CORS config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

HTML:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/safari-script-error/foo.js" />
```

which contains:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 69) { // "e" button
    throw new Error("Oh shoot");
  }
});
```

JS:

```js
window.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/astashov/pen/yoEvRB

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, and only shows "Script error." in Safari (I have Version 10.0.3 (12602.4.8)).

How to make it work in Safari too?

Comment: BTW, your `<script>` element cannot be self-closing - I wonder if this could be the cause of the errror?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How to make it work in Safari too?

You can’t. Current Safari versions don’t support giving error messages to the `onerror` callback in the cross-origin case—even if a `crossorigin` attribute is specified on the `script` element.

Safari did support it previously, but subsequently regressed at some point.

There’s an open bug for this at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=132945

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that CORS is the problem. It appears that support for the global `onerror` handler isn't in every browser.

See: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Actually, it probably is related to CORS.

> When a syntax(?) error occurs in a script, loaded from a different origin, the details of the syntax error are not reported to prevent leaking information (see bug 363897). Instead the error reported is simply "Script error." This behavior can be overriden in some browsers using the crossorigin attribute on  and having the server send the appropriate CORS HTTP response headers.  A workaround is to isolate "Script error." and handle it knowing that the error detail is only viewable in the browser console and not accessible via JavaScript.

Comment: No, even if I replace `onerror` with `addEventListener("error`, it still behaves the same way. Also, `onerror` works just fine for me for the exceptions originated from the same domain in Safari.