# Q-Unit Global Failure

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I have just attempted to set up Q-Unit Testing, for my javascript functions. However, I seem to be getting an error of **Global Failure**

Within my JS file : `script.js`, I have to have the test code above all of my JS code, else the unit tests do not run and I only get the global failure message. However, if I paste the unit tests above all of the JS functions, the tests do then run but I still get the global failure error. 
[image: error2]

Can someone guide in the right direction.

**test-script.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Q-Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.10.0.css">


</head>
<body>

    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.10.0.js" integrity="sha256-X1fQXHSYGxa4V2bqkEAQW0DQGSxJrKveasahr959o28=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
 function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}

QUnit.test( "square", function( assert ) {
  var result = square(2);
  assert.equal( result, "4", "square(2) should be 4." );
});

//Normal JS functions are below here
```

Comment: Are you using Safari?  If so, this question might be worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844565/script-error-errors-in-window-onerror-in-safari-only.  Do you get the same message in another browser?

Comment: Hi @LukeWoodward no I'm using Chrome, I also tried to run them in incognito mode and it still appeared.

Comment: Odd, I couldn't reproduce on Chrome, Firefox, Edge nor IE on Windows.  I got one passing test and no global errors regardless of the order of functions and tests within script.js.

Comment: @LukeWoodward how strange, quite frustrating, I'm running in Chrome on my MAC, does the same within Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer to this one as I think by including the CDN link for jQuery that has solved the global failure error, as it is no longer appearing.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```