# What is instantSearchSDKJSBridgeClearHighlight?

Tags: javascript, ios, microsoft-edge, sentry

Sometimes I get ReferenceError in my sentry with this instantSearchSDKJSBridgeClearHighlight. Google says nothing.
<strike>All I found is https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android and https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios that may be related to my issue.</strike>

I got 53 issues from 5 different users and all of them Edge Mobile on iphone.
Maybe someone knows what this thing is (or know method how to know)?

**Edit:** I also found [this issue](https://github.com/RecordReplay/devtools/issues/3618) using github search. Same issue as mine and created by bot

Comment: Started seeing the same thing in our Sentry logs. I sort of assumed it has to do with a browser extension?

Comment: You can also try to send feedback to the relevant team. Click the three dot icons `(...)` at the bottom of the browser, select the send feedback option, and edit the content to send.

Comment: @XudongPeng Sure, thank you. I'll install it and report error

Comment: So only guys from microsoft know what is this...
Also I got no success getting answer from them about this issue

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a bug in the Bing Instant Search feature in Edge on iOS; the feature tries to call a function that no longer exists. Thanks for the bug; I've passed it along to the feature owners.

The basic idea is that for Edge on iOS the actual web engine is not our normal one (Blink); it is instead Safari's WkWebView.

In order to implement features like Bing's instant search, we have to inject JavaScript into the pages we load. Then our outer browser calls those JavaScript functions we injected.

Here, someone goofed and got rid of (or renamed) the injected JavaScript function, but failed to remove/update the browser code that tries to call that injected JavaScript.

So users who are watching the browser's error logs see an error message saying "Hey, there's no such function."

This is normally harmless, but if you have "Sentry" code that watches for error messages and complains about them to the website developers, it starts complaining about this error message we're causing.

Comment: For the past 2 years now, I've been encountering miscellaneous client-side errors reported only by the very unhelpful `window.error` event message ["Script error" with no further details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853382/159145) - and this _only_ ever happens with visitors using Edge iOS. It seems with iOS 15 the `window.error` event now shows more useful details (like the `instantSearchSDKJSBridgeClearHighlight` keyword, which is how I found this QA). Given that Edge iOS is spamming my client-side error logs, is it possible to instruct Edge iOS to **not** inject any scripts into my pages?

Comment: Are there any updates for that? since Sentry keeps complaining about it. Also, from Safari browser and not specifically with Edge.

Comment: @TvDev Sentry will complain you forever with this. You just need to ignore it (and link this SO post) because some users may have outdated version of their browser which they may keep forever.